# Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product\\/(?P<slug>[^/]+)\\/$']

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to build an ecommerce website, but i am can proceed due to the error shown above. Thanks

url.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from .**views import ItemDetailView, HomeView, checkout

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns =[
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('checkout/', checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product')
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Item
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "home-page.html"

class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product-page.html"

def checkout(request):
    return render(request, 'checkout-page.html')
```

html template

```
<a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="{% url 'core:product' %}" target="_blank">Products</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass the slug also to the template ( in "`home-page.html`")

```
{% for product in object_list %}
<a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="{% url 'core:product' product.slug %}" 
target="_blank">{{ product.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i have done that, the for loop is making the product to appear twice on the webpage, i want it to appear just one since it is a navigation bar

Comment: in list view you will have list of all products, if you want to limit it you can slice the queryset, Item.objects.all()[:1]

Comment: add a get context data method in Home view.     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = Item.objects.all()[:1] 
        return context